# Change default PlantUML skin Options

Tags: plantuml, docsify

I have to do a docsify documentation for school and for that we got a template-documentation.

So i was changing some things and looking into the index.html of the documentation. 
I noticed a part of the script code in the index.html looking like this:

```
// Optionen fuer PlantUML Import
plantuml: {
   skin: 'classic'
},
```

The comment is in german but in english it would be: "Options for PlantUML Import".

After seeing the "skin: 'classic' i thought that probably means that there are other skins and so i dived into google and searched for skins.

I found ways to change colors and looking of the PlantUML but nothing hat to do with this script part in the index.html.

Does anyone know other skins? and also how to change it? Are there other placeholders for 'classic' that change the skin of the PlantUML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the plugin documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/docsify-plantuml#skin) only two values are accepted in the `skin` option:

- `default`: as they say, a cleaner version (https://github.com/matthewjosephtaylor/plantuml-style: the white one)
- `classic`: the classic version (https://github.com/matthewjosephtaylor/plantuml-style: the yellow with red border one)